# How to properly convert a DateTime to a specific TimeZone?

Tags: c#, datetime

I'm trying to convert this date: `Sunday 26 August 2018 18:30:00` to a `GMT +2`, so the result should be: `Today, 26 Aug 2018, 20:30`.

Now the following code works:

```
var unixTimeStampValue = Convert.ToInt64(1535308200);
var unixTimeStamp = unixTimeStampValue.Split("-")[0].Replace("t", "");
unixTimeStamp = Regex.Match(unixTimeStamp, @"\d+").Value;

DateTime dtDateTime = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0);
dtDateTime = dtDateTime.AddSeconds(Convert.ToInt64(unixTimeStamp));

TimeZoneInfo timeInfo = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Central Europe Standard Time");
var date = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(dtDateTime, timeInfo);
```

but the problem is that if I run this on linux I'll get:

> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: The time zone ID 'Central Europe Standard Time' was not found on the local computer --> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not find file '/usr/share/zoneinfo/Central Europe Standard Time'.

The problem appear only on linux, how can I fix that? There is another way to get this conversion?

Comment: Most Unix boxes use the [IANA](http://iana.org/tz) time zone database. If you need to run on both Windows and Linux, your options are: 1) Work out whether you want "Central Europe Standard Time" or "Europe/Paris" based on the system (not too bad if it's a single time zone - if you need multiple time zones, it would get fiddly); 2) Use [Noda Time](https://nodatime.org) or a similar package that lets you use IANA time zones on both Windows and Linux.

Comment: @DaisyShipton Thanks for the reply, could you show an example with NodaTime? I never used it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As requested, an example with [Noda Time](https://nodatime.org):

```
using System;
using NodaTime;

class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Instant instant = Instant.FromUnixTimeSeconds(1535308200);
        DateTimeZone zone = DateTimeZoneProviders.Tzdb["Europe/Budapest"];
        ZonedDateTime zoned = instant.InZone(zone);
        Console.WriteLine(zoned);
    }
}
```

Output on my machine:

```
2018-08-26T20:30:00 Europe/Budapest (+02)
```

You can convert the `ZonedDateTime` back to a `DateTime` if you need to, but it's best to use Noda Time for as much of your date/time handling as you can, to get the full benefit.

Comment: could you take a look at this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52035424/cannot-get-the-correct-timezone